# React deployed in Nginx, AJAX Axios don't work

Tags: ajax, reactjs, spring, spring-mvc, nginx

I want to combinate frontend with backend on the cloud virtual machine like DigitalOcean or AWS or Microsoft Azure.

- Frontend: React
- Backend: Spring Spring MVC Mybatis + Tomcat (NOT Spring Boot)

So I have searched for some methods using Nginx on the Internet. Firstly, I am going to combinate the frontend with backend on the local (macOS). Secondly, if the method succeeded, I will deploy the project on the cloud host. But, it occurs an error in the first step.

When I typed the `localhost:8081` site, the browser can show the normal website. But no any backend data. I have supposed that the Nginx configuration may be inappropriate for access to the backend.

Maybe add `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/example_war_exploded/;` in nginx.conf, but I got the JSP content without any CSS or JavaScript. I only want to access data by AJAX Axios.

#### Related files

1. nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8081;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html/build;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

2. Backend, Tomcat URL: `http://localhost:8080/example_war_exploded/`
3. Spring MVC Controller

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/comment")
public class CommentController {
   @GetMapping(value = "/comments")
}
```

4. Frontend Axios

```js
axios.get(`/comment/comments`).then((response) => {
  this.setState({
    comments: response.data,
  });
});
```

What should I do... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you want to get JSON from the backend, we need to access `http://localhost:8080/example_war_exploded/comment/comments`.

So, we should add the code snippet in nginx.conf.

```
location ^~ /comment {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/example_war_exploded/comment;
}
```

Completed code in nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        off;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8081;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html/build;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        # New
        location ^~ /comment {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/example_war_exploded/comment;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```